# How do I build a linked list function that can make changes to nodes and to the head pointer?

Tags: c, linked-list, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have built a linked list in C where each node is a character.
So my linked list represents a string.
I am trying to create a function that removes a number of characters starting from a position.
I wrote the following:

```
listNode *removeChars(listNode *wordList, int pos, int lnth) {
    listNode *curr = wordList;
    listNode *prev = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < pos-1; i++) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;        
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lnth; i++)
       curr = curr->next;
    prev->next = curr;
    return wordList;
}
```

where `lnth` represents the number of characters to remove starting from `pos`.
It works fine...EXCEPT when my `pos == 1`.
To handle this exception, I wrote the following code:

```
void removeFirstChar(listNode **wordList, int lnth) {
    listNode *curr = *wordList;
    for (int i = 0; i < lnth; i++)
        curr = curr->next;
    *wordList = curr;
}
```

My question is:

How do I merge both functions so I end up with one function that can handle both cases, `pos = 1` and `pos > 1`?

Comment: Would an `if( pos == 0 ) call remove_first else call remove_chars` work?

Comment: Typically a LL is assembled from allocated memory blocks from the heap. Are you sure you won't be leaking memory if you "edit out" some nodes from a LL (without freeing the allocation)?

Comment: @Thad Include the list definition in your question.eu Freitas Filho

Comment: Does your `pos` index start from one?

Comment: I recommend to not use linked lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you should create new nodes in the list dynamically using function malloc.

It means that you need to free allocated nodes that must be removed from the list.

You do not check whether the pointer to the head node is equal to `NULL`. So in any case your function can invoke undefined behavior.

If a function can change an object as for example the pointer to the head node then you should pass the object to the function by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the pointer within the function it can get a direct access to the original object and change it.

Your function can be declared and defined the following way

```
size_t removeChars( listNode **wordList, size_t pos, size_t n ) 
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while ( *wordList != NULL && pos )
    {
        --pos;
        wordList = &( *wordList )->next;
    }

    if ( pos == 0 )
    {
        while ( *wordList && n-- )
        {
            listNode *tmp = *wordList;
            *wordList = ( *wordList )->next;
            free( tmp );
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

The function returns the actual number of removed nodes from the list.

As in C indices start from 0 then the value of the parameter `pos` also starts from 0.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad-from-Moscow. I don't understand ```wordList = &( *wordList )->next;```. Never saw this type of expression before. Where can I find more about it? Clearly it keeps the linked list connected when deleting nodes in the middle. I thought it was the same as ```*wordList = ( *wordList )->next;``` but confirmed that it is not.

Comment: For example, with ```wordlist = &( *wordlist )->next;```, how do I access the character? ```printf("%c\n", &(*wordList)->letter);``` doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now, because this works: ```printf("%c\n", (*wordList)->letter);```

Comment: @ThadeuFreitasFilho For example if you have a pointer declared like listNode *wordList; then a pointer to this pointer will look like &wordList. Data member next is a pointer that is accessed like ( *wordList )->next. So a pointer to the pointer will look like &( *wordList )->next.